# How can I find each ascendent of a record in a self-referential table without N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am working with a self-referential model (`Category`) in a Ruby on Rails app, which has the following columns:

`id`, `name`, `level`, `parent_id`

`belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category', optional: true`

The concept is that a `level` 1 category can have a `level` 2 subcategory, which can have a `level` 3 subcategory, etc.

For example:
`Category id: 1, name: 'Dessert',   level: 1,  parent_id: nil`
`Category id: 2, name: 'Cold',      level: 2,  parent_id: 1`
`Category id: 3, name: 'Cake',      level: 3,  parent_id: 2`
`Category id: 4, name: 'Ice Cream', level: 3,  parent_id: 2`
`Category id: 5, name: 'Sponge',    level: 4,  parent_id: 3`

I'd like to find each ascendent of a record, regardless of how many `levels` deep it is. I then want to concatenate all the names, in ascending order, into one string.

i.e., if I'm starting with `Sponge`, I'd like a method which returns `"Dessert - Cold - Cake - Sponge"`

What I have so far works but is an n+1 and doesn't feel very Railsy:

```
def self.concatenate_categories(order)
      category = order.category
      categories_array = []

      order.category.level.times do
        categories_array.push category.name
        category = Category.find(category.parent_id) if category.parent_id.present?
      end

      categories_array.reverse.join(' - ')
    end
```

If this order is for `Sponge`, I get `"Dessert - Cold - Cake - Sponge"`.
If the order is for `Cake`, I get `"Dessert - Cold - Cake"`.

Comment: Sponge isn't an ascendant of Sponge, or is it? What does ascendant mean in this context?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'd like to include the child (`Sponge`) and all of its ascendants (`Cake`, `Cold`, `Dessert`); Sponge's parent is Cake, Cake's parent is Cold, Cold's parent is Dessert, Dessert has no parent.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know that answer to the RDBMS question, but we're using Postgres... hope that helps

Comment: Adding the `postgresql` tag, maybe someone with more experience can give you a better answer which can then "translated" to Rails Active Record.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a recursive CTE to get each category parent based on its parent_id:

```
WITH bar AS (
  WITH RECURSIVE foo AS (
    SELECT
      categories.id,
      categories.name,
      categories.parent_id
    FROM categories
    WHERE categories.id = 5
    UNION
    SELECT
      p.id,
      p.name,
      p.parent_id
    FROM categories p
    INNER JOIN foo f
    ON f.parent_id = p.id
  ) SELECT name FROM foo ORDER BY id
) SELECT STRING_AGG(name, ' - ') FROM bar
```

Comment: That's not limiting to the scope of the Sponge's lineage. for example, in a more complex dataset I get:  
```Dessert - Hot - Cake - Cold - Main Course - Ice Cream - Sponge```  
  
I'm not well versed in SQL, so I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: What do you mean with _lineage_. What would be the expected output in that case? Here I'm blindly assuming a category parent is one with a minor level.

Comment: Sure, that's the problem.

Comment: So, using the dataset in the question, the query you provided returns: `Dessert - Cold - Cake - Ice Cream - Sponge`... `Ice Cream` is not a parent of `Sponge` (`Cake` is the parent of `Sponge`). Per the question, my expected output is `"Dessert - Cold - Cake - Sponge"`

Comment: The problem with this answer is that they're not being returned in the correct order (and exclude the child). It's also a departure from nice, clean, rails code, which we're looking to avoid.

Comment: I tested pretty much with the same records you added and it is not excluding the child. The order is stated by the recursive CTE, while the outer CTE does the string concatenation. Don't know what you mean with _It's also a departure from nice, clean, rails code, which we're looking to avoid_.

Comment: What I mean is, this is pure SQL and Rails. I'm taking your answer as one of the options, though, so I'll discuss with the team. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sure, glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I haven't tested that code, but you get the idea, join as many times as there are levels and query once. Depending on how many levels there are, your solution can be faster than too many joins.

```
def self.concatenate_categories(order)
  scope = order.category

  categories_array = if category.level > 1
    scope = scope.select('categories.name')
    order.category.level.downto(1) do |l|
      scope = scope.joins("JOIN categories as c#{l} ON categories.id = c#{l}.parent_id")
                   .select("c#{l}.name")
    end
    scope.to_a
  else
    Array.wrap(scope.name)
  end
  categories_array.reverse.join(' - ')
end
```

Comment: Interesting... I'll have a play with this and see how it fairs. Thanks